# How to implement push notification with react-native

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native, push-notification

Socket.io channel disconnects whenever the app is in background or closed, how to keep channel connected all time because i have to include push notification feature to my chat application.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> What is the best way to handle notifications on react-native

It depends on the platform that you support, to receive mobile push notification on the device the best way is to implement the platform specific solution.

> Why do you do that ?

Because even if you app is close or in background, the user will get notification on the screen and you can handle it

> For iOS:

You have use an [APNs](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/APNSOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH8-SW1) server to send push notification

> For Android:

You have to use [GCM](https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/introduction-to-push-notifications)

> To make the implementation of that even easier you can use services like:

- [Urban Airship](https://www.urbanairship.com)
- [Amazon SNS](https://aws.amazon.com/fr/sns/)
- [Pusher](http://pusher.com)
- [OneSignal](https://onesignal.com)
- [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com)

> How to implement that with react-native ?

You have really good libraries to do that:

With [react-native-push-notification](https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification)

here is an example with this library:

```
var PushNotification = require('react-native-push-notification');

PushNotification.configure({
    onRegister: function(token) {
        // Call when your device register the token
        // You have to pass this token to the API or services like OneSignal, Pusher etc...
        console.log( 'TOKEN:', token );
    },

    // This is trigger when a remote notification is received or open
    onNotification: function(notification) {
        console.log( 'NOTIFICATION:', notification );
    },

    // This is only for Android
    senderID: "YOUR GCM (OR FCM) SENDER ID",

    // This is only for iOS
    permissions: {
        alert: true,
        badge: true,
        sound: true
    },

    // Should the initial notification be popped automatically
    // default: true
    popInitialNotification: true,

    // Ask the permission to receive notifications
    requestPermissions: true,
});
```

You also have libraries that implement the service of your choice like :

- Pusher: [react-native-pusher-push-notifications](https://github.com/b8ne/react-native-pusher-push-notifications)
- OneSignal: [react-native-onesignal](https://github.com/geektimecoil/react-native-onesignal)
- Firebase: [react-native-firebase](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase)

I hope my answer help you

Comment: @JulienKode can you please tell me how to fire some action when user tap on notification ?